# Ordenar os k maiores resultados utilizando dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Eu consigo selecionar os k maiores resultados de uma table no R. Por exemplo, se k for igual a 5, eu obtenho o seguinte resultado:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

top_n(mpg, 5, wt=displ)
# A tibble: 5 × 11
  manufacturer              model displ  year   cyl      trans   drv   cty
         <chr>              <chr> <dbl> <int> <int>      <chr> <chr> <int>
1    chevrolet           corvette   6.2  2008     8 manual(m6)     r    16
2    chevrolet           corvette   6.2  2008     8   auto(s6)     r    15
3    chevrolet           corvette   7.0  2008     8 manual(m6)     r    15
4    chevrolet    k1500 tahoe 4wd   6.5  1999     8   auto(l4)     4    14
5         jeep grand cherokee 4wd   6.1  2008     8   auto(l5)     4    11
# ... with 3 more variables: hwy <int>, fl <chr>, class <chr>
```

Entretanto, meus resultados não estão ordenados de acordo com a coluna `displ`. Eu gostaria que as linhas da table estivessem em ordem decrescente, da seguinte maneira:

```
top_n(mpg, 5, wt=displ)[order(top_n(mpg, 5, wt=displ)$displ, decreasing=TRUE), ]
# A tibble: 5 × 11
  manufacturer              model displ  year   cyl      trans   drv   cty
         <chr>              <chr> <dbl> <int> <int>      <chr> <chr> <int>
1    chevrolet           corvette   7.0  2008     8 manual(m6)     r    15
2    chevrolet    k1500 tahoe 4wd   6.5  1999     8   auto(l4)     4    14
3    chevrolet           corvette   6.2  2008     8 manual(m6)     r    16
4    chevrolet           corvette   6.2  2008     8   auto(s6)     r    15
5         jeep grand cherokee 4wd   6.1  2008     8   auto(l5)     4    11
# ... with 3 more variables: hwy <int>, fl <chr>, class <chr>
```

O código funciona, mas eu estou achando ele feio. De que maneira eu poderia simplificá-lo para obter o mesmo resultado? Note que eu utilizo o comando `top_n(mpg, 5, wt=displ)` duas vezes, o que imagino que possa deixar meu código mais lento se a table for muito grande. Existe alguma maneira de obter este mesmo resultado de maneira mais elegante?

Comment: Sobre a parte do "feio": será que usar a sintaxe do `dplyr` com `%>%` não ajudaria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `dplyr` faz uso de encadeamento e do pipe operator (`%>%`) para melhorar a leitura do código e torná-lo mais sucinto. Além disso, também dispõe da função `arrange()` para ordenar os resultados.

```
res1 <- top_n(mpg, 5, wt=displ)[order(top_n(mpg, 5, wt=displ)$displ, decreasing=TRUE), ]

res2 <- mpg %>% top_n(5, displ) %>% arrange(desc(displ))

identical(res1, res2)
[1] TRUE
```

A documentação sobre [pipe operator](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/652/pipe-operators-and-others/2132/basic-use-and-chaining) no stackoverflow é excelente.

Comment: Eu estou começando a usar o `dplyr` e não conhecia o `arrange`. Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 3):

Outras formas de fazer a mesma coisa:

```
library(dplyr)

mpg %>% arrange(desc(displ)) %>% slice(1:5)
mpg %>% filter(row_number(desc(displ)) <= 5)
```